# Basic point multiplication with G in libsecp256k1

Tags: bitcoin-core, ecdsa, secp256k1, c

I'm trying to work out a minimal example with the bitcoin core secp256k1 library but am a bit lost due to the many options available. Concretely, I simply want to use libsecp256k1 to multiply the generator point G as defined by the standard with an integer k, ie `H = k*G`.

So far, I found `secp256k1_scalar_mul`, which multiplies two scalars and `secp256k1_fe_mul` which multiplies two field elements, while close neither is what I'm looking for. So I was wondering if someone could point me to a suitable function in libsecp256k1?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/blob/7b50483/include/secp256k1.h#L566 ?

Comment: @MCCCS Exactly, you should turn that into an answer. The functions listed by OP are internal operations that aren't exposed outside the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, as Pieter Wuille said, all exposed functions (only those that you'd need to use) are in [`include/secp256k1.h`](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/blob/7b50483/include/secp256k1.h)

You can use [`secp256k1_ec_pubkey_create`](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/blob/7b50483/include/secp256k1.h#L566) like this:

```
secp256k1_context *sign = secp256k1_context_create(SECP256K1_CONTEXT_SIGN);
secp256k1_pubkey pubkey;

// Here our private key is 1, little endian
const unsigned char seckey[32] = {1};

if (!secp256k1_ec_pubkey_create(sign, &pubkey, seckey)) {
    // Private key out of range
    // abort!
    secp256k1_context_destroy(sign);
    exit(1);
}

// Use 65 and SECP256K1_EC_UNCOMPRESSED for uncompressed public key
unsigned char outpubkey[33];
size_t written_bytes = 33;
secp256k1_ec_pubkey_serialize(sign, outpubkey, &written_bytes, &pubkey, SECP256K1_EC_COMPRESSED);

printf("Public key: ");

for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
    printf("%.2x", (unsigned int) outpubkey[i]);
}

printf("\n");

secp256k1_context_destroy(sign);
```

Whose output can be verified with [ThePiachu's tool](https://gobittest.appspot.com/Address) and the private key `0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`